# Projection coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, coordinate-system

I have raster image that projected by WGS1984 UTM Zone 37N. But my shapefile was Adindan UTM Zone 37N. Due to this, it doesn't overlay the same. I tried to define projection for the raster image to Adindan UTM zone 37N, But not match. So, how can I display the raster image in Adindan UTM Zone 37N without change WGS1984 UTM Zone 37N?

Comment: What's your platform? Where you are trying to overlay both?

Comment: I tried to overlay this in Arcmap 10.1. by making a layer to Adindan UTM Zone 37N.

Comment: hmm.. I don't use ArcGIS, rather I use QGIS. In QGIS you can enable CRS on fly to some particular EPSG and then import all the layers on that. If you have to perform this task again n again then better learn in ArcGIS, otherwise if possible give me the data so that I can convert them to one CRS.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Project Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007q000000) function with *WGS1984 UTM Zone 37N* as input coordinate system and *Adindan UTM Zone 37N* as output coordinate system.

The input coordinate system should be entered automatically if it is defined on the raster. However, the fact that they don't overlap in Arcmap suggests that's not the case for either your raster, shapefile or both.

You should also be aware of the difference between the *Project* and *Define projection* functions. The first one will change the coordinates of your file to a new a coordinate system while staying in the same spot on Earth. The latter will only write to your file which coordinate system it is already in (eg. where 0, 0 is), and wont change any of your coordinates (as they are stored in the file).